# tensorflow TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow V2.2 and run into TyepError when I do model.evaluate. Can someone advise what the issues may be? A screenshot of the execution and error message is shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to define a metric when you compile the model `model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')`

in this way during evaluation, loss and accuracy are returned

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if you don't have `metric='accuracy'` in the `model.compile`, don't try to extract it in `model.evaluate`.

So, you can change:

> loss, acc= model.evaluate(df, df_y, verbose=0)

to

> loss = model.evaluate(df, df_y, verbose=0)